# There is no default resource specified in the "resources.pri" file

Tags: windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I am developing Windows 8.1 Store application in C-Sharp/XAML, while running App Certification Kit, I am facing this error.

**Resource reference "Assets\StoreLogo.png": There is no default resource specified in the "resources.pri" file.**

I am unable to resolve this one. Kindly help.

Comment: I have the exact same problem...did you solve it already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I have solved this problem by placing correct sized store images in assets and cleaning the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well... I have exactly the same error. Tried everything, spent like several hours redeploying and retesting. Then I tried to run the certification test on a fresh machine: it did succeeed.
So .. if you are running standalone certification test against an application installed on a machine, where several former versions of the application were installed... just give it a try on a brand new fresh OS :)